# Artifacts in my rendering, due to my modeling?

Tags: modeling, rendering

I have modeled a typical church from my city and I don't get how my render reacts on some points:

[image]

I don't understand why I have so whitish objects in rendering (those white pillars mainly don't look realistic), I did check by recalculating the normals inside/outside and removed double vertices. Probably there are still some features to correct I am not aware yet. This is why I am asking to the community.

It isn't much essential as I will try to print this as an object. But I would like to know still why do I get such results.

Comment: Did you checked if those pillars aren't simply using a different material ?

Comment: I double checked but it isn't, or it is simply my configuration on my nodes I guess now. I tried to create a "resin" effect alike. So probably that thin objects are more "translucent" than bigger ones.